# how to separate string from unformed string

Tags: python

I have this format of string

```
 2013-06-05T11:01:02.955 LASTNAME=Jone FIRSTNAME=Jason PERSONNELID=salalm QID=231412 READER_NAME="CAZ.1 LOBBY LEFT TURNSTYLE OUT" ACCESS_TYPE="Access Granted" EVENT_TIME_UTC=1370480141.000 REGION=UTAH
```

some of them looks like this

```
 2013-06-05T11:15:48.670 LASTNAME=Ga FIRSTNAME="Je " PERSONNELID=jega QID=Q10138202 READER_NAME="CAZ.1 ELEVATOR LOBBY DBL GLASS" ACCESS_TYPE="Access Granted" EVENT_TIME_UTC=1370481333.000 REGION=UTAH
```

I want to extract value of PERSONNELID,REGION,ACCESS_TYPE,EVENT_TIME_UTC

I was going to use split(" ") however READER_NAME and ACCESS_TYPE value has bunch of spaces
Can I convert to JSON and search by key

What is the way to extract those strings.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You _could_ convert this to JSON (or to CSV, or to something else that already has a parser), but that's likely to be almost as hard as just parsing it in the first place. If you can't find a parser that works on your data with only a trivial transformation, it's better to write a parser (whether by using regex, a parser generator, explicit string processing with recursive descent, whatever).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One hack I've found useful in the past is to use [`shlex.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
>>> s = '2013-06-05T11:01:02.955 LASTNAME=Jone FIRSTNAME=Jason PERSONNELID=salalm QID=231412 READER_NAME="CAZ.1 LOBBY LEFT TURNSTYLE OUT" ACCESS_TYPE="Access Granted" EVENT_TIME_UTC=1370480141.000 REGION=UTAH'
>>> split = shlex.split(s)
>>> split
['2013-06-05T11:01:02.955', 'LASTNAME=Jone', 'FIRSTNAME=Jason', 
'PERSONNELID=salalm', 'QID=231412', 'READER_NAME=CAZ.1 LOBBY LEFT TURNSTYLE OUT',
'ACCESS_TYPE=Access Granted', 'EVENT_TIME_UTC=1370480141.000', 'REGION=UTAH']
```

And then we can turn this into a dictionary:

```
>>> parsed = dict(k.split("=", 1) for k in split if '=' in k)
>>> parsed
{'EVENT_TIME_UTC': '1370480141.000', 'FIRSTNAME': 'Jason', 
'LASTNAME': 'Jone', 'REGION': 'UTAH', 'ACCESS_TYPE': 'Access Granted', 
'PERSONNELID': 'salalm', 'QID': '231412', 
'READER_NAME': 'CAZ.1 LOBBY LEFT TURNSTYLE OUT'}
```

As @abarnert points out, you can keep more of the information around if you want:

```
>>> dict(k.partition('=')[::2] for k in split)
{'2013-06-05T11:01:02.955': '', 'EVENT_TIME_UTC': '1370480141.000', 'FIRSTNAME': 'Jason', 'LASTNAME': 'Jone', 'REGION': 'UTAH', 'ACCESS_TYPE': 'Access Granted', 'PERSONNELID': 'salalm', 'QID': '231412', 'READER_NAME': 'CAZ.1 LOBBY LEFT TURNSTYLE OUT'}
```

Et cetera.  The key point, as he nicely put it, is that the syntax you've shown looks a lot like minimal shell syntax.  OTOH, if there are violations of the pattern that you've shown elsewhere, you might want to fall back to writing a custom parser.  The `shlex` approach is handy when it applies but isn't as robust as you might want.

Comment: I like this, even though it extracts much more data than the OP asked for.

Comment: Yup - great way of doing it - +1 - my turn to say I should have thought of this trick ;)

Comment: Since you beat me to it, let me suggest the only piece from my answer so you can add it here and I can delete mine. If you use `partition` instead of `split`, you don't need the `if '=' in k` part.

Answer (score 3):

Let's analyze the problem: You want to match one of the four identifiers, then an `=` sign, and then either a quoted string or a sequence of non-whitespace characters.

That's a perfect job for a regular expression:

```
>>> s= ' 2013-06-05T11:01:02.955 LASTNAME=Jone FIRSTNAME=Jason PERSONNELID=salal
m QID=231412 READER_NAME="CAZ.1 LOBBY LEFT TURNSTYLE OUT" ACCESS_TYPE="Access Gr
anted" EVENT_TIME_UTC=1370480141.000 REGION=UTAH'
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"""\b(PERSONNELID|REGION|ACCESS_TYPE|EVENT_TIME_UTC)
...                        =
...                        ("[^"]*"|\S+)""", re.VERBOSE)
>>> result = regex.findall(s)
>>> result
[('PERSONNELID', 'salalm'), ('ACCESS_TYPE', '"Access Granted"'), 
 ('EVENT_TIME_UTC', '1370480141.000'), ('REGION', 'UTAH')]
>>> dict(result)
{'EVENT_TIME_UTC': '1370480141.000', 'PERSONNELID': 'salalm', 
 'ACCESS_TYPE': '"Access Granted"', 'REGION': 'UTAH'}
```

**Explanation:**

`\b` makes sure that the match starts at a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

`"[^"]*"` matches a quote, followed by any number of non-quote characters, and another quote.

`\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters.

By enclosing the "interesting" parts of the regex in parentheses, building [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), you get a list of tuples for each part of the match separately.

Comment: You could use (something like) `[A-Z_]+` rather than specifying keys exactly?

Comment: @AndyHayden: Well, he/she said that only four specific keys were of interest.

Comment: @user1413449: What do you mean, they already are separated... for example `[item[1] for item in regex.findall(s)]` would give you all the values. Or `dict(regex.findall(s))` would give you a dictionary with proper key/value pairs.

Comment: what if I only want to get value of PERSONNELID?

Comment: Accessing a dict's specific values is very easy: After you've done `d=dict(regex.findall(s))`, you can simply do `d['PERSONNELID']` to get 'salalm'.

Answer (score 3):

Looking for an existing parser is a good idea. If you can find a format that already describes your data, or that you can trivially convert your data into, you win.

In this case, converting to JSON seems like it'll be as much work as parsing in the first place.

But you're just looking to split into simple `value` and `name=value` components, where the `value` part can be quoted… those are the same rules as minimal shell syntax. So, [`shlex`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) will do it for you:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('2013-06-05T11:01:02.955 LASTNAME=Jone FIRSTNAME=Jason PERSONNELID=salalm QID=231412 READER_NAME="CAZ.1 LOBBY LEFT TURNSTYLE OUT" ACCESS_TYPE="Access Granted" EVENT_TIME_UTC=1370480141.000 REGION=UTAH')
['2013-06-05T11:01:02.955',
 'LASTNAME=Jone',
 'FIRSTNAME=Jason',
 'PERSONNELID=salalm',
 'QID=231412',
 'READER_NAME=CAZ.1 LOBBY LEFT TURNSTYLE OUT',
 'ACCESS_TYPE=Access Granted',
 'EVENT_TIME_UTC=1370480141.000',
 'REGION=UTAH']
```

You will still need to separate each `name=value` pair out into name and value components, but that's just `namevalue.split('=', 1)`. But it's pretty much implicit that you need to do that separately given that you've got some elements that aren't name-value pairs (`2013-06-05T11:01:02.955`).

Of course you can always choose to treat them as name-value pairs with empty values:

```
>>> dict(namevalue.partition('=')[::2] for namevalue in shlex.split(s))
{'2013-06-05T11:01:02.955': '',
 'ACCESS_TYPE': 'Access Granted',
 'EVENT_TIME_UTC': '1370480141.000',
 'FIRSTNAME': 'Jason',
 'LASTNAME': 'Jone',
 'PERSONNELID': 'salalm',
 'QID': '231412',
 'READER_NAME': 'CAZ.1 LOBBY LEFT TURNSTYLE OUT',
 'REGION': 'UTAH'}
```